# Preservation of intervals theorem proof completion

Tags: real-analysis

The preservation of intervals theorem states that if $f:\langle a,b\rangle\to\mathbb{R}$ *(where $\langle a,b\rangle$ is an interval in reals, open or closed)* is continuous, then $f(\langle a,b\rangle)$ is an interval.

Proof:

$m:=\inf\limits_{\langle a,b\rangle} f, M:=\sup\limits_{\langle a,b\rangle} f$

1. Prove that $f(\langle a,b\rangle)\subset \langle m, M\rangle$.
   $$\forall x\in\langle a,b\rangle \quad m\leq f(x)\leq M$$

Both of the inequalities can be strict only when $\langle a,b\rangle$ is a closed interval and therefore it has been proved that $\forall x\in\langle a,b\rangle\quad  f(x)\in\langle m,M\rangle$.

2. Prove that $f(\langle a,b\rangle)\supset \langle m, M\rangle$.

I think applying Bolzano's Intermediate Value Theorem is the next step, however I need a closed interval for that. I have considered using the following function:

Let $f^*:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, such that $f^*(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a+0}f(x),\ f^*(b)=\lim\limits_{x\to b-0}f(x),\ \forall x\in(a,b)\quad f^*(x)=f(x)$.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: the statement is wrong, for consider $f(x)=x^2$ restricted to $(-1,1)$, then it's image is $[0,1)=\{x|0\leq x<1\}$, did you state the theorem correctly? My version is only for "closed and bounded" intervals, or for intervals in general, but the image is not an interval of the same type as the domain

Comment: I have indeed stated the theorem wrong.

Comment: probably that is why you weren't able to proceed